# JMS serializer With zf2 and ajax

Tags: jquery, zend-framework2, jms, serialization

- I am tring to use JMS serializer library with ZF2 and Doctrine 2

**Requirement:**

- Controller Action is called through Ajax
- Controller Action will returned serialized object as response
- After successful response, Ajax will populated object value to phtml dynamically

I have implemented above requirement but facing one fatal issue:
**Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded JMS Serializer**

- I googled but didnt find any good example JMS Serializer with ZF2

Answer (score -1):

With the help of My Team Lead, 
We got the solution, Means we are able to serialize the Doctrine Object.

**This Documentation may help while installing JMS serializer library With ZF2**

https://github.com/Spea/JMSSerializerModule/blob/master/docs/index.md

To Allow only some property to serialize, We can use Annotation, This link may help for understanding Annotation with in JMS library

http://jmsyst.com/libs/serializer/master/cookbook/exclusion_strategies